# Python, removing required quotes from input()

Tags: python

Ok, I've been putting together a script but there's an annoying thing that happens with the input part. Depending on which version of python I have, I either need to include quotes for my input or I don't. With python 2.7, I need quotes; with python 3.3, I don't. For example:

```
filename = input('Enter Update File: ')
print(filename)
```

With python 2.7, I need to surround my input with quotes or it raises a NameError; in python 3.3, I don't.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Python 2 and Python 3 are not the same language. Do not use `input()` in Python 2, and don't try to use the same codebase on both.

Comment: To clarify: your `input()`s require quotes on a certain system?

Comment: Yes, but I guess it has to do with file associations... maybe. the one computer that has only had 3.3 on it, does not require the quotes. I probably had 2.7 at one time on my linux machine and I know I've had 2.5 and 2.7  on the other windows desktop. Right now, I'm just going ahead and researching making it pop up an explorer window instead...

Comment: Actually, I wrote a 7000 line Python script that works on 2.x and 3.x; it's quite doable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Python 2.x you need to be using `raw_input()` rather than `input()`. On the older version of Python, `input()` actually evaluates what you type *as a Python expression,* which is why you need the quotes (as you would if you were writing the string in a Python program).

There are many differences between Python 3.x and Python 2.x; this is just one of them. However, you could work around *this specific difference* with code like this:

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass

# now input() does the job on either 2.x or 3.x
```

Comment: Outstanding! that does the trick. Thanks!